# Making image inline with text on Card component

Tags: css, react-native

I'm currently trying to display title text and a corresponding image on a react native element Card component.However, I can't seem to move any of the images in to a proper position. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? I have looked through much of the styling documentation as well. Thank you!

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Card
            containerStyle={{
              flex: 1.3,
              backgroundColor: "#A0D6B4",
              borderRadius: 20,
              shadowColor: "#000",
              shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 6,
              },
              shadowOpacity: 0.37,
              shadowRadius: 7.49,
              width: 375,
              height: 150,

              elevation: 12,
            }}
          >
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: "System",
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: "#F8F4FF",
                    paddingVertical: 1,
                    paddingHorizontal: 0.3,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  }}
                >
                  Stages of Pregnancy{"\n"}and You
                </Text>
                <Card.Image
                  style={{ width: 270, height: 150, flexWrap: "wrap" }}
                  source={require("../../../assets/seconstage.png")}
                ></Card.Image>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 100, width: 1000 }}></View>
            </View>
          </Card>
</ScrollView>
</View>
```

styles.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
       backgroundColor: '#F0FFF0'
    },
    title: {

    },
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 120,
        width: 90,
        alignSelf: "center",
        margin: 30
    },
    input: {
        height: 48,
        borderRadius: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginLeft: 30,
        marginRight: 30,
        paddingLeft: 16
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: '#788eec',
        marginLeft: 30,
        marginRight: 30,
        marginTop: 20,
        height: 48,
        borderRadius: 5,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonTitle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    footerView: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 20
    },
    footerText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#2e2e2d'
    },
    footerLink: {
        color: "#788eec",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 16
    }
})
```

[image: Picture of how it looks right now]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside of View like this

```
<View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end',}}>
   <Card.Image
      style={{ width: 150, height: 150, flexWrap: "wrap" }}
      source={require('../assets/image/img.jpg')}/>
</View>
```

Or Instead of Card.Image use Image and import it from react-native and align it anywhere you can use alignSelf in this directly or you can use justifyContent  "space-between" in parent view.

```
<Card>
   <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', padding: 16,}}>
      <Text
       style={{
         fontFamily: "System",
         color: "#F8F4FF",
         fontSize: 20,
         paddingVertical: 1,
         paddingHorizontal: 10,
         fontWeight: "bold",
       }}>
        Stages of Pregnancy{"\n"}and You
      </Text>
      <Image
         style={{ width: 150, height: 150, }}
         source={require("../../../assets/images/img.jpg")}
      />
   </View>
</Card>
```